# How to make my WPF MainWindow a singleton?

Tags: wpf, singleton, mainwindow

I want to make my MainWindow a singleton because I want to make accessing it from all other windows in my app easier. But I couldn't make it run. Here is what I did.

As usual, I made the MainWindow contractor private, and created a `public static MainWindow Instance` property to return a static instance. When I just run it without any other changes, I got "No Source Available" error. I googled the Internet and found one related topic at http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/xamlc-singleton-class-80578.shtml. However, I couldn't make it work as suggested there. Some suggest to make a change in MainWindow.xaml from

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
```

to

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow.Instance"
```

Which looks logical. However, when I did this, I got tons of compiling errors (first one says the namespace TestApp already contains a definition of 'MainWindow'.)

I found many articles on the Internet about how to make single instance app. I'm not looking for this. I just want to make my MainWindow a singleton. I have done it in WinForm apps many times.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make the `MainWindow` a singleton, these are the steps you need to make: 
Add a `MainWindow` `Instance` to `MainWindow` class...

```
public static MainWindow Instance { get; private set; }
```

Note: set accessor is private so that nobody else can set it to anything else.

Add a static constructor in `MainWindow` and make the constructor of `MainWindow` `private`, like this...

```
static MainWindow()
{
    Instance = new MainWindow();
}

private MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Now remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from your `App.xaml` file so that no default window is launched when you start the application. Catch the Startup event of your App class in App.xaml.cs like this:

```
public App()
{
    ...
    Startup += App_Startup;
    ...
}

void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    TestApp.MainWindow.Instance.Show();
}
```

Comment: You have to do this in a static constructor or lazily in the `Instance` getter. Also, for singleton you usually make constructors private. In your example, consumers can create multiple MainWindow instances and the last one will be assigned to `Instance`

Comment: At least if you want to properly implement the singleton pattern. This code will obviously work in the sense that other classes can access the main window from the `Instance` property, but it's not "pure" singleton IMHO

Answer (score 18):

Not sure about making it singleton, but why would you want to? You can simple use  Application.Current.MainWindow to get the Application.MainWindow property anytime from anywhere in your application.. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=VS.90).aspx.

```
Window mainWin = Application.Current.MainWindow;
mainWin.Title = "This will be set as the title of the Main Window";
```

Making it singleton still does not make sense to me - how does that make it more accessible? You can always save reference to your main window in a public static variable - this could be set in the constructor of your main Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static MainWindow myMainWindow; // ASSUMPTION: only one MainWindow is ever constructed otherwise this will be overwritten by latest such instance

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        myMainWindow = this;
    }
}
```

But then given the above Application.Current.MainWindow why bother..

Comment: What about other part of code doint this Winow1 = new Window1() , it will create another instance.

Comment: Mnl. Yes, I know I can do that, but I just want to make my life a little easier. So, I want to call MainWindow.Instance.DoSomething() instead of ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).DoSomething().

Comment: Understood, in that case saving a static reference as above should make your life easier.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from your **App.xaml** file. WPF will not launch any window for you anymore.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

Add a handler to the `Startup` event of your `App` class in **App.xaml.cs**.
In this handler call the `Show()` method of your singleton instance.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Startup += new StartupEventHandler(App_Startup);
        }

        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            WpfApplication1.MainWindow.Instance.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `App` class has a property called `MainWindow`, hence in `App_Startup()` I prefixed the `MainWindow` class with the namespace!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for the quick answsers. The key point is that I have to remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from App.xaml. Thanks also for the tip of static contructor. Another point I want to mention is that we can also override OnStartup to startup the main window (just to make a few lines shorter):

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            TestApp.MainWindow.Instance.Show();
        }
    }
```